# rails asset-pipeline caching fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

rails 3.2.13 asset pipeline serving fonts from cache not logging?

I am using the following gem [font-awesome-sass-rails](https://github.com/littlebtc/font-awesome-sass-rails) and am having trouble with the font files being cached and the server not logging the request. I have recently upgraded from v2 to v3 of the gem. But rails is still serving v2 of the font files. If I remove the font files from the gem run bundler restart webrick clear the browser cache rails still serves the files. The only way I can bust the cache is if I change the font url in the sass file.

It seems font files are being cached by sprockets and cannot be cleared?

I have tried to clear the sass cache:
    rm -fr tmp/sass-cache

Any one have any suggestions?  I am also wondering if it is normal that requests for cached assets do not show up in the server log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this fixed it:

```
rake assets:clean
```

I am unsure why the fonts were the only files effected by having precompiled assets. I must have had partially precompiled assets.

Comment: Is config.assets.digest set to true? If not, make it true, that will help by forcing an update based on the new digest.